Why doesn't Gandhi tell the truth to Jeevan in the G.O.A.T.?
In the movie the Greatest of All Time, when Jeevan reunites with Gandhi(for bad intentions), why doesn't Gandhi tell his son that he thought that he had been burnt after being abducted when he was 5? At least that might have helped him recover his past memories with his biological family, which had been erased after Menon first put him in a juvenile facility to traumatize him, and then later appear that he 'saved' him, so that Menon could easily use Jeevan to avenge his family's death on Gandhi.
